# How to store all different types of locators(xpath, Css, Link, ID etc) in a single variable in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to store all different types of locators*(xpath, Css, Link, ID etc)* in a single variable and perform some action on it as in the below statement.

"`webdriver.findelement(variable).click();`" here the variable could be "b`y.id,by.xpath,by.css..etc`"
I have written the below code but got stuck at converting the string to web element to perform some action on it.

```
public void Element(){          
        try{
              String locator = new String("xpath=//div[@id='pageTitle']");
                  if(locator.startsWith("//"))
                  System.out.println("Locator value if 
                          starts with slash is\t" +locator);
              else 
              {
                  if(locator.contains("=")){
                  String retnval[] = locator.split("=");
                  String type = "findElement(By."+retnval[0]+"(";            
                  int index= locator.indexOf("=");
                  locator=locator.substring((index)+1);                   
                  String element =type.concat(locator+")");
                  System.out.println(element);
                   getElement.click();
                 }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

**Output is:**

```
findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='pageTitle'])
```

am aware of the below code, but want to try something different without ever using the locator type *(xpath,id,css,name etc)* in my code or help me know how to convert the string to a Web element.

```
if(locator.contains("xpath="))
                    locator = locator.substring(6);
                webDrvElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
            }
            else if(locator.contains("id=")){
                locator = locator.substring(3);
                webDrvElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id(locator));
            } 
            else if(locator.contains("name=")){
                locator = locator.substring(5);
                webDrvElement = webDriver.findElement(By.name(locator));
            } 
            else if(locator.contains("css=")){
                locator = locator.substring(4);
                webDrvElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(locator));
            }
```

Comment: You can see this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096306/how-to-convert-string-to-by-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Reflection as below :-

```
 String locator = "xpath=//li[@id='menu-item-72']/a";
 String[] locatorValArr = locator.split("=");

 String locatorType = locatorValArr[0];
 String locatorValue = "";
 for(int i = 1; i < locatorValArr.length; i++)
     locatorValue += locatorValArr[i]+"=";
 locatorValue = locatorValue.replaceAll("\\=$", "");

 Class byClass = Class.forName(By.class.getName());
 Method getMethodBy = byClass.getMethod(locatorType, String.class);
 By newById = (By) getMethodBy.invoke(null, locatorValue);

 driver.findElement(newById).click();
```

Same way we can do it for cssSelector, name, class, id and other locator types

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable information. This is exactly what i was looking for. But i noticed some extra space in newById. This is the output of the above code: By.xpath: //li[@id='menu-item-72']/a
After "By.xpath:" and the before the value "//li[@id='menu-item-72']/a", there is a space, which i tried to trim but couldn't succeed.

Comment: try doing like this :- String a = " abc"; a = a.replaceAll("^\\s", ""); // this will replace leading whitespaces

Comment: Once the object is converted to By.Class can we trim the leading spaces?
Here, in my case the string is not carrying any space but while the conversion process from string object to by object, there is some leading space before the value and after the colon(:).                         
By.xpath: //li[@id='menu-item-72']/a